# Авторизация на uCoz сайте с помощью РНР

Tags: curl, php, auth, ucoz

Нужно РНР-скриптом авторизоваться на uCoz сайте, чтобы потом скриптом запросами добавлять материалы на сайт. Пробовал так:

```
function get_url_code($url, $post=null, $refer=null, $cookie='cookie.txt')
{
    if ($refer == null) $refer = false;
    //Иницализация библиотеки curl.
    if ($ch = curl_init())
    {
        //Устанавливаем URL запроса
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        //При значении true CURL включает в вывод заголовки.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        //Куда помещать результат выполнения запроса:
        //  false – в стандартный поток вывода,
        //  true – в виде возвращаемого значения функции curl_exec.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //Установим значение поля User-agent   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);   // переходит по редиректам
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');        // обрабатывает все кодировки
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120); // таймаут соединения
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);        // таймаут ответа
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);       // останавливаться после 1-ого редиректа
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $refer);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, ($post)?true:false); // использовать данные в post
        if ($post) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

        //Выполнение запроса
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        //Особождение ресурса
        curl_close($ch);
        //Вывести полученные данные
        return $data;
    }
    else
    {
        die("<strong>cUrl error!</strong>");
    }
}

function auth()
{
    $auth = array(
        'email' => 'email',
        'pass' => 'pass',
        'secmode' => 1,
    );
    echo $data = get_url_code('http://XXXXXXXXXX.uid.me/', $auth, 'http://XXXXXXXXXX.uid.me/');
}
auth();
```

Авторизация не происходит. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Погано робиш, Назаре.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу, вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением, а когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).